# CSS Techniques to Hide Scroll Bars and Disable Text Selection?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm working on a web project where I need to customize the appearance and behavior of a container element. Specifically, I want to remove the scroll bars from the container and prevent users from selecting text within it. I've tried various CSS properties and techniques, but I haven't found a solution that works reliably across different browsers.

Here's what I've attempted so far:

```
<div class="custom-container">
  <!-- Content goes here -->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.custom-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Hides scroll bars, but still allows scrolling */
  user-select: none; /* Prevents text selection, but doesn't work consistently */
}
```

While setting `overflow: hidden` successfully hides the scroll bars, it still allows users to scroll the content using mouse or touch gestures. Additionally, the `user-select: none` property prevents text selection, but it's not supported uniformly across all browsers.

**Could someone suggest a reliable CSS-based solution to achieve both hiding scroll bars and preventing text selection within the container element? Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!**